# How can I add specific role to user who react to the message

Tags: discord.js

I'm trying do create a bot that can add specific role to the user who react to the message with the emoji listed.

With the code below, I can check who reacted to the message and i can also check what emoji they react with, but when I am trying to add role to them, error pops up say *user.addRole is not a function* is there any way to solve this problem? Thanks a lot!

Code that create an embed message for user to react

```
    let args = message.content.substring(PREFIX.length).split(" ");

    if(message.content.toLowerCase() === '?roles' && message.author.id === 'adminId' && message.channel.id === 'channel id'){
        const role = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setTitle("ROLES")
        .setColor('#6a0dad')
        .setDescription(' - ROLE1\n⚔️ - ROLE2\n - ROLE3')
        message.channel.send(role).then(re => {re.react(''),re.react('⚔️'),re.react('')});
        message.awaitReactions().then(collected=>{
            const reaction = collected.first();
        })
    }
```

Code that get the react user and trying to add role

```
const bot = new Discord.Client({ partials: ['MESSAGE', 'CHANNEL', 'REACTION'] });
 bot.on('messageReactionAdd', async (reaction, user) => {
    if (reaction.partial) {
        try {
            await reaction.fetch();
        } catch (error) {
            console.log('Something went wrong when fetching the message: ', error);
            return;
        }
    }
    if(reaction.message.id === 'id of that embed message sent'){
        if(reaction.emoji.name === ""){
            //console.log('ROLE1');
            user.addRole('id of role 1');
        }
        if(reaction.emoji.name === '⚔️')
            //console.log('ROLE2');
            user.addRole('id of role 2');
        if(reaction.emoji.name === '')
            //console.log('ROLE3');
            user.addRole('id of role 3');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're trying to add a role to a `User`. When you should be adding the role to a `GuildMember`.  As you can see here: [messageReactionAdd](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-messageReactionAdd) returns a `User`. However Users don't have a `.roles` only GuildMembers do. However you have two ways you can get the GuildMember easily:

This way you have to make sure the message is from a TextChannel not a DMchannel.
`if(reaction.message.type === "text") let member = reaction.message.member`;

### OR

This way allows the user to react to ANY message the bot has cached.
`let member = bot.guilds.get('<id of the server>').members.get(user.id);`

Then you do what @Syntle said: `member.roles.resolve('<id of role>');`
The choice of how to get the member is up to you.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I've tried the first one and it said Lexical declaration cannot appear in a single-statement context and the second one it said bot.guilds.get is not a function......

Comment: I was simpfying on the first one. Of course you wouldn't declare a variable in a if statement and use `member.roles.add` outside of the if statement. Make the if statement have brackets nad put member.roles.add inside of the if statement with the member declaration.

`bot.guilds.get` is what I rembered from when I used to code in discord.js. try `.resolve` instead

Comment: I've try it and no error pops out everythings working fine but the problem is that the `if(reaction.message.type === "text") let member = reaction.message.member;` returns the object of my bot(the one who send the message) but not the user who react to the message did i do anything wrong?

Comment: The second one solved the problem using `let member = bot.guilds.resolve('<id of the server>').members.get(user.id);` then do `member.roles.resolve('<id of role>')` successfully add role to user who add reaction thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

`user.addRole()` needs to be replaced with [`member.roles.add`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMemberRoleManager?scrollTo=add).

Comment: I've tried this and I still get an error TypeError: Cannot read property 'add' of undefined

Comment: Are you using discord.js v11 or v12?

Comment: i'm using v12.0.2

Comment: Can you log `user` to see if it's returning a user?

Comment: yes, it return a User object with id,bot,username,disciminator,avatar,lastMessageID and lasstMessageChannelID